# Luxrender - How to select API 2.x?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, external-applications

I've searched around for a way to preview a Luxrender render in Blender's viewport but cannot seem to find the solution to this error. When I click the render mode for the viewport it comes up with:

> ERROR Viewport rendering is only available when API 2.x is selected!

Comment: without having read the full post, here is a page with a screenshot showing how to switch between API 1.x and API 2.x: http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxBlend25_LuxCore#Switching_to_LuxCore_.28API_2.x.29

Answer (score 2):

I'm just setting up a Mac and aren't too familiar but having just downloaded the latest LuxRender1.5 and installed LuxBlend, I see the API choice is not called API2.x, rather it is called *LuxCore API (experimental)* so I am assuming this is the 2.x
Here is a screenshot:

[image: lux API]

EDIT: But be aware that there may be performance issues when using the viewport. This post mentions and gives some explanation:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appleseed-dev/YZ5dR9qvUV0